# DataObjects::SyntaxError Help Needed: Ruby, Sinatra, & DataMapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm putting together my first Sinatra application and I'm having issues with the database relationships.  I've tried everything I know how to do on this (not much) and I'm still scratching my head.

Here's the error I keep getting:

```
    <DataObjects::SyntaxError: 
    ERROR: relation "lovers" does not exist 
    LINE 1: ...ug", "lover_name", "last_updated", "sidebar" 
    FROM "lovers" W... ^ (code: 16908420, sql state: 42P01, query: 
    SELECT "id", "slug", "lover_name", "last_updated", "sidebar" 
    FROM "lovers" 
    WHERE "slug" = 'home' 
    ORDER BY "id" 
    LIMIT 1, 
    uri: postgres:localhost/keeprdb?scheme=postgres&user=&password=&host=localhost&port=&path=/keeprdb&query=&fragment=&adapter=postgres)>
```

Here's the Git Hub info github.com/Jonnyread/keepr

Any help in how I could go about fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

If you need anything else from me, please don't hesitate to ask.

Since I'm not sure what the relevant code is, here's the application.rb file:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'sinatra'
    require 'sinatra/flash'
    require 'dm-core'
    require 'dm-validations'
    require 'dm-types'
    require 'dm-migrations'
    require 'dm-postgres-adapter'
    require 'rdiscount'
    require 'rack-ssl-enforcer'

    DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/keeprdb')

    class Lover 
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :id,           Serial
      property :slug,         String
      property :lover_name,   String
      property :content,      Text
      property :last_updated, DateTime  
      property :sidebar,      Enum[ :yes, :no ], :default => :no
    end

    DataMapper.finalize

    # Global variables
    NAV_TITLE = 'Keepr'
    FOOTER = '<em>"This page is maintained by that wild demi-god Jahmed."</em> -                 <strong>All Praises</strong>'

    # Authentication
    # use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
    #   [username, password] == [username, password]
    # end

    # Force all connections to use SSL
    # use Rack::SslEnforcer

    # Converts page into post slug
    def slugify(content)
        content.downcase.gsub(/ /, '-').gsub(/{^a-z0-9_-}/, '').squeeze('-')
    end

    # Sets index page as "home"
    get '/' do
        redirect '/home/'
    end

    # Creates a new lover from "new lover" form

    post '/' do
        if params[:userinput].empty?
            redirect '/'
        else
        @lover = Lover.first_or_create(:lover_name => params[:userinput], :slug => slugify(params[:userinput]))
        @lover.content = "This is a new lover.  Congrats!  You should write what you remember about her.  That is of course if you remember - you animal."
        @lover.last_updated = DateTime.now
        @lover.save
        flash[:notice] = "Lover created successfully.  Hope you're that successful too"
        redirect "/#{@lover.slug}/"
        end
    end

    # List all lovers in the database
    get '/all/' do
        @lover = Lover.new
        @lover.lover_name = 'All Lovers'
        @lover.slug = 'all'
        @lovers = Lover.all
        @sidebars = Lover.all(:sidebar => 'yes')
        erb :all
    end

    # Displays requested lover
    get '/:url/' do
        @lover = Lover.first(:slug => params[:url])
        if @lover == nil
            flash[:notice] = "That chick don't exist boy."
            redirect '/home/'
        else
            @lovers = Lover.all
            @sidebars = Lover.all(:sidebar => 'yes')
            erb :show
        end
    end

    # Edits requested note
    get '/:url/edit' do
      @lover = Lover.first(:slug => params[:url])
      @sidebars = Lover.all(:sidebar => 'yes')
      erb :edit
    end

    # Saves user edits to a lover
    post '/:url/edit' do
        @lover = Lover.first(:slug => params[:url])
        @lover.lover_name = params[:lover_name]
        @lover.content = params[:content]
        @lover.sidebar = params[:sidebar]
@lover.last_updated = DateTime.now
if lover.slug != 'home'
    @lover.slug = slugify(params[:lover_name])
end
@lover.save
flash[:notice] = "Change to Lover is saved. Bitch."
redirect "/#{@lover.slug}/"
    end

    # Readies requested lover for deletion
    get '/:url/delete' do
        @lover = Lover.first(:slug => params[:url])
        @lovers = Lover.all
        @sidebars = Lover.all(:sidebar => 'yes')
        erb :delete
    end

    # Deletes specified lover
    delete '/:url/delete' do
        @lover = Lover.first(:slug => params[:url])
        @lover.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'You just dropped that bitch.  You should probably go out and find another.'
        redirect '/home/'
    end

    # Redirects user to homepage if a lover is not found
    not_found do
        flash[:notice] = "Dude, we all know you didn't book that girl.  Straight up."
        redirect '/home'
    end
```

Here's the section that the error is in:

```
    # Displays requested lover
    get '/:url/' do
        @lover = Lover.first(:slug => params[:url])
        if @lover == nil
            flash[:notice] = "That chick don't exist boy."
            redirect '/home/'
        else
            @lovers = Lover.all
            @sidebars = Lover.all(:sidebar => 'yes')
            erb :show
        end
    end
```

Here's the Rakefile:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'sinatra'
    require 'sinatra/flash'
    require 'dm-core'
    require 'dm-validations'
    require 'dm-types'
    require 'dm-migrations'
    require 'dm-postgres-adapter'
    require 'rdiscount'
    require 'rack-ssl-enforcer'

    DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/keeprdb')

    class Lover 
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :id,           Serial
      property :slug,         String
      property :lover_name,   String
      property :content,      Text
      property :last_updated, DateTime  
      property :sidebar,      Enum[ :yes, :no ], :default => :no
    end

    DataMapper.auto_migrate!

    task :setup do 
        @lover = Lover.create(:slug => 'home')
        @lover.slug = 'home'
        @lover.lover_name = 'Home'
        @lover.content = 'This is the beginning of the next step my man. -Jahmed'
        @lover.last_updated = DateTime.now
        @lover.sidebar = :no
        @lover.save 
    end
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code, specifically, your models and migration schema?

Comment: Sounds like the migrations haven't run. Are you able to check the database more directly and check the tables are there?

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.rb` source code, immediately following the line

```
DataMapper.finalize
```

add the line

```
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

`::auto_upgrade!` tries to make the database schema match your model(s).  It `CREATE`s new tables, and add columns to existing tables, as necessary.  For more information, see: http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html

Does that fix it?